# Select row id that has unique value provided

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table called category in which a user can store the value of a spending category. Here food and sports is one combination and they have the same cat_id in the database.

```
cat_id  spending_category
1       food
1       sport
2       food
2       sport
2       movie
3       food
3       movie
```

I want to query this table and find out if there is already an existing category combination of only food and sport. if yes return that id.i want to used that id to tag the similar id, which means I should get 1 here. not 2 because id 2 is a combination of food, sport and movie.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cat_id
FROM category
GROUP BY cat_id
HAVING SUM(spending_category = 'food') + SUM(spending_category = 'sport') = COUNT(*)
```

The conditions in the SUM() functions return 1 or 0. Just compare it to the number of entries in each group.

cat_id 2 would have 3 entries, therefore it would not be returned.